# MySql-multiple where conditions

Tags: mysql, r, where-clause

Hello and thanks ahead for the help.

I'm using the MAX database in order to do some research. I'm trying to limit my observations to a specific diagnosis, where there are no co infections of interest from the same visit.

Here is what I have so far:

```
y<-dbGetQuery(conn, "select visit from database 
WHERE diag IN ('diag1', 'diag2')group by visit") 
~this yields 100 obs

y2<-dbGetQuery(conn, "select visit from database 
WHERE diag IN ('diag1', 'diag2' ) 
and diag NOT IN ('diag3', 'diag4') group by visit")
~this also yields 100 obs
```

Since I am getting the same number, I am pretty sure this is not working the way I want it to. I'm new to R and MySql so any advice would be very appreciated.

I guess one something I should have explained that there can be multiple diagnosis's for each visit. Maybe an example would help me explain my question better:

**Patient:                   Visit:         Diag:**
    a    1               diag1
a                           1               diag3
b                           2              diag2
b                           2               diag5
c                           3                diag1

So since I am only interested in analyzing patients who patients who had a diag1 or diag2 without a diagnosis of diag3 or diag4, I would only be interested in patients B and C in my analysis, and not patient a.

Comment: I don't understand why you would think they would be different. Can you give some sample data and the results you expect for that data?

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, I've added an example that hopefully helps! Essentially, I never specified that there can be multiple diagnosis's for each visits

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in your SQL queries. The query

```
select visit from database WHERE diag IN ('diag1', 'diag2') group by visit
```

is identical to

```
select visit from database WHERE diag IN ('diag1', 'diag2' ) and diag NOT IN ('diag3', 'diag4') group by visit
```

The reason is that the additional condition in the second query `and diag NOT IN ('diag3', 'diag4')` is necessarily true, given the first condition which is common to both queries, `diag IN ('diag1', 'diag2')`. In other words, if `diag` is one of `'diag1'` and `'diag2'`, then it cannot be one of `'diag3'` and `'diag4'`.

---

**Edit:** Looking at your example data, I think I understand what you're after. Your second query must be rewritten as follows:

```
select o.visit from database o where o.diag in ('diag1','diag2') group by o.visit
having not exists (select 1 from database where visit=o.visit and diag in ('diag3','diag4'))
```

The `having` clause is basically like the `where` clause, except it's applied *after* the grouping (defined in the `group by` clause) has been applied, so you can filter on each group as a whole. In your case, the query prior to the application of the `having` clause will select all of visits 1, 2, and 3, and then the `having` condition I wrote excludes any visits that also involved a diagnosis of `'diag3'` or `'diag4'`, which ends up just excluding visit 1.

Note: I've assumed that each `visit` number is unique to a single `patient`, e.g. if `patient='a'` had `visit=1`, then no other patient can have `visit=1`, because that's how things look in your example data, and that's what your queries imply. If that's not true, the query (actually both of your queries) would have to be rewritten to group by both `patient` and `visit`, you would have to select both `patient` and `visit` in your select clauses (to get unambiguous result-set data), and, in the second query, the `having` clause would have to correlate on `patient` as well as `visit`.

Comment: Thanks @bgoldst, you make it look so simple! And yes the conditions you mention in your second paragraph are true, each visit is unique. However, the code is not working. But maybe I'm not using it correctly, can you explain what your o and o. mean?

Comment: In my query `o` is a *table alias*. It was necessary to distinguish the `o.visit` name in the correlated subquery, where I basically need to join the "outer" record (that's what I had in mind when I selected `o` as the alias) from the `database` table with the "inner" record that the DBMS scans when it applies the subquery. In other words, the `visit=o.visit` join condition would not work if you said something like `visit=visit`, because both of those names would bind to the inner record.

Comment: This is a good summary of aliases in SQL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL).